# Easymock matcher for Object Array

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock

I have the following class:

```
public class Listener{

@Autowired
private Handler handler;


public void receiveMessage(Message<String> message) {
    String xmlMessage = message.getPayload().toString();

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(InfoTO.class);

    infoTO = (InfoTO) xstream.fromXML(xmlMessage);


    UserDetailTO[] userDetailTO = { new UserDetailTO(infoTO.getUserId(), null) };
    handler.sendEmail(userDetailTO);

}
```

}

My test method:

```
   @Test
public void testRecieve() {
    UserDetailTO[] userDetails={new UserDetailTO("zzzz",null)};

    Handler handlerMock=EasyMock.createMock(Handler.class);
    handlerMock.sendEmail(aryEq(userDetails));
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    EasyMock.replay(handlerMock);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(listener, "handler", handlerMock);

    String message = "Test Payload";
    Message<String> finalMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
    listener.receiveMessage(finalMessage);

}
```

When i run this test class, i get Assertion error for Unexpected method call. Its expected because in the test class, the UserDetailTO instance inserted in the array will not match with the instance created in the Listener class.

But then, how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a problem with  `UserDetailTO.equals(Object)` method.  Are 2 `UserDetailTO` objects equal if they have the same user id and null 2nd parameter?

Also your line `EasyMock.expectLastCall();` isn't needed.  When a mock is in replay mode, all void methods are automatically "expected".  You only need to call `EasyMock.expectLastCall()` if you want to perform some other behavior like throw an exception or invoke an `IAnswer` when that void method is called.

For example if you wanted the `sendEmail` method to throw an Exception:

```
Exception expectedException = new Exception(...);
...
handlerMock.sendEmail(aryEq(userDetails));
EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(expectedException);

EasyMock.replay(handlerMock);
```

Comment: equals is not a problem. Two UserDetailTO objects are equal if they have the same user id and null 2nd parameter. But aryEq is only comparing the reference of the objects inside the array instead of calling UserDetailTO.equals(Object). Don't we have anything like isAnyArray() in EasyMock?

Comment: Then does `infoTO.getUserId()` return "zzzz" ?

Comment: My mistake...you were right, infoTO.getUserId() does not return "zzzz". Thanks. But still i would like to know if there is any other option...something like isAnyArray().

Comment: The idea of "anyArray()" can be done in EasyMock by `isA(UserDetailTO[].class)`